# 419 (unknown status) on PUT request using laravel

Tags: json, laravel, flutter

I'm trying to update a value in database using put request but I have faced CSRF error and I didn't know how to fix it in flutter so I used `Route::withoutMiddleware(['csrf'])`;

I'm expecting the record to be updated but I still have the error:

> PUT http://localhost/update/mike@fmaila.com 419 (unknown status)

I also tried to add `http://localhost/*`, in VerifyCsrfToken.php file
how can I fix it?

laravel:

```
public function updateStatus(Request $request, $email)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'is_active' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $record = AddSeller::where('email', $email)->firstOrFail();
        $record->is_active = $validatedData['is_active'];

        $record->save();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Record updated successfully'], 200);
    }
```

flutter

```
Future<void> updateState(String email, String newValue) async {
  final apiUrl = 'http://localhost/update/$email'; 
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  final requestData = {'is_active': newValue}; 
  try {
    final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(requestData),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Record updated successfully');
    } else {
      print('Failed to update record: ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the route should be in the api routes so it doesn't apply the web middleware that would require csrf protection for action verbs (PUT, PATCH, POST, etc)

Comment: thanks , i dont know if i got it well but it also required csrf token ,how can i provide it with flutter
i knew that in blade laravel i should use @csrf in html form but im using flutter text fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining routes for APIs, don't define them in `web.php` because most of the time stateful routes are defined there. Instead, define API Routes in `api.php`, these routes are stateless so you don't need to send a CSRF token with a request.

So you need to define your route in `api.php`. Also by default, these routes are prefixed with `api\` so your new route will be,

```
http://localhost/api/update/$email
```